# how can i solve the error invalid x in a mediation analysis?

Tags: multiple-regression, error, mediation

when i run this script:

```
model.1 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ studval_acad_T1, data = diss) 
model.M1 <- lm(selfworth_T1   ~ studval_acad_T1, data = diss)
model.Y1 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ studval_acad_T1 + selfworth_T1, data = diss)

model.2 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ studval_soc_T1, data = diss)
model.M2 <- lm(selfworth_T1   ~ studval_soc_T1, data = diss)
model.Y2 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ studval_soc_T1 + selfworth_T1, data = diss)

model.3 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ excl_acad_T1, data = diss)
model.M3 <- lm(selfworth_T1   ~ excl_acad_T1, data = diss)
model.Y3 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ excl_acad_T1 + selfworth_T1, data = diss)

model.4 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ excl_soc_T1, data = diss)
model.M4 <- lm(selfworth_T1   ~ excl_soc_T1, data = diss)
model.Y4 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ excl_soc_T1 + selfworth_T1, data = diss)

model.5 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ studval_acad_T1, data = diss)
model.M5 <- lm(disc_T1   ~ studval_acad_T1, data = diss)
model.Y5 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ studval_acad_T1 + disc_T1, data = diss)

model.6 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ studval_soc_T1, data = diss)
model.M6 <- lm(disc_T1   ~ studval_soc_T1, data = diss)
model.Y6 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ studval_soc_T1 + disc_T1, data = diss)

model.7 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ excl_acad_T1, data = diss)
model.M7 <- lm(disc_T1   ~ excl_acad_T1, data = diss)
model.Y7 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ excl_acad_T1 + disc_T1, data = diss)

model.8 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ excl_soc_T1, data = diss)
model.M8 <- lm(disc_T1   ~ excl_soc_T1, data = diss)
model.Y8 <- lm(uncert_bel_T1 ~ excl_soc_T1 + disc_T1, data = diss)

med.out <- mediation::mediate(model.M1, model.M2, model.M3, model.M4, model.M5, 
                              model.M6, model.M7, model.M8, model.Y1, model.Y2, 
                              model.Y3, model.Y4, model.Y5, model.Y6,
                              model.Y7, model.Y8, treat='studval_acad_T1' + 
                              'studval_soc_T1' + 'excl_acad_T1' + 'excl_soc_T1', 
                              mediator='selfworth_T1' +'disc_T1', 
                              boot=TRUE, sims=500, data = diss)
```

i get the error "Error in robustSE && boot : invalid 'x' type in 'x && y'" for the last part (med.out...)

i think it has something to do with the fact that i am doing a mediator analysis with multiple independent variables (studvalacad/soc, exclacad/soc) as well as two mediators (selfworth, disc) for the dependent uncert.bel....

i have never done such a complex analysis before, so i am very thankful for every help :)

thank you, Theresa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect. `mediate()` only accepts a single Y model and a single M model. If you want to include multiple mediators and treatment variables, use `mediations()` and read its help file to ensure you are entering its arguments correctly.